# Parsing JSON array of objects with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, parsing

What I am trying to do is parse this JSON: http://www.theunjust.com/test/container.php

And just get it to show at this point...

Here is my current code(its all jacked up)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jsonurl = "container.php";
  $.getJSON(jsonurl, function(data) {         
    $.each(data.encompass,function(i,valu){
    var content,
    cont = '',
    tainers = valu.containers;

  $.each(tainers, function (i) {
    var tid = tainers[i].TID,
    top = tainers[i].Top,
    cat = tainers[i].Category,
    date = tainers[i].Date,
    icon = tainers[i].Icon,
    clink = tainers[i].ContainerLink,
    uid = tainers[i].UniqueID;

        cont += '<a href="' + clink + '">' + uid + '</a> ';
        $('ul').append('<li>' + tid + ' - ' + top + ' - ' + cat + ' - ' + date + ' - ' + icon + ' - ' + clink + ' - ' + uid + ' (' + cont + ')</li>');
    }); 
  }); 
}); 
});
```

I know that the code doesn't make sense, this is more of a learning experience for me rather than a functioning tool. The issue may be in the JSON data itself, if that is the case, what stackoverflow web service post would you recommend?

What I eventually aim to do is run multiple web services and combine them... So that container.php loads and has all of the information that is required for a wrapping div, then entries.php loads and fills the divs that was generated by containers..

I'm currently learning jQuery and Honestly, I'm not to this level yet, but I am getting there pretty quick.

I really appreciate the help, and would like if you could point me in the direction to become a JSON parsing pro!

Answer (score 1):

`containers` contain single node. So simply use

```
$.each(tainers, function (i, v) {
    var tid = v.TID,
    top = v.Top,
    cat = v.Category,
    date = v.Date,
    icon = v.Icon,
    clink = v.ContainerLink,
    uid = v.UniqueID;

    cont += '<a href="' + clink + '">' + uid + '</a> ';
    $('ul').append('<li>' + tid + ' - ' + top + ' - ' + cat + ' - ' + date + ' - ' + icon + ' - ' + clink + ' - ' + uid + ' (' + cont + ')</li>');
});
```

Comment: Odly enough It is still not working, I'm going to try passing JSON via a string instead of web service.

Answer (score 1):

The program shows how to read json and store data into textbox:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("Test.json",function(data){
       $.each(data,function(key,value){
           alert(data[key].attrib1name);
           alert(data[key].attrib2name); 
           $('input').val(data[key].enterpriseName);
           activities=data[key].activities;
           console.log(value);
       });
   });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery as a hammer for every nail for starters. This is a core JavaScript problem.

There are only two structures to parse in JavaScript. Arrays and objects.

For objects, use:

```
for(var x in obj){ alert(x + ':' + obj[x]) } //would alert <property name>:<property value>
```

For arrays use a loop like you would in PHP. In JS while loops are nice for arrays:

```
var i = someArray.length;
//if you don't want to loop backwards just do someArray.reverse()

while(i--){
   //do stuff to someArray[i] here
}
```

JSON is just an object literal in JavaScript. The simplest type of object. Just a place to stick properties. A property can be an array, a value, or another object. The only thing to watch out for is objects that reference other properties in an object (results in infinite loops when attempting to parse) which is a really dumb thing to do with JSON (not even sure that would pass validation).